# Implementation of push_back via emplace_back

Tags: c++, push, move, forward, emplace

Suppose we want design a container `C` similar to `std::vector`. Is it a good idea to implement `push_back` by calling `emplace_back`, such as:

```
template <typename T>
class C {
  public:
    ...
    template <typename Args...>
    void emplace_back(Args&&... args) { 
      ... // uses T(std::forward<Args>(args)...) internally
    }
    void push_back(T value) {
      emplace_back(std::move(value));
    }
    ...
};
```

or, alternatively:

```
    template <typename U>
    void push_back(U&& value) {
      emplace_back(std::forward(value));
    }
```

?

Comment: This type of question may get a better response from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This is exactly how it is implemented for vector in msvc (const& and && overloads).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for pointing this out, haven't known about this site. Is it commonly used? There is only 4,917 C++ tagged questions on CR, in contrast to 526,886 on SO.

Comment: @Sopel What version are you referring to? That is not correct for VS2015 (14.0).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux i'm talking about version 14.1 +, which is shipped since vs2017

Comment: @DanielLangr It's less active and younger than Stack Overflow but you can get better results because the question would better target it's user base.

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes, codereview is commonly used. Do be aware that the expected question format is very different from on Stack Overflow, so you'll want to check the help center and maybe try to get guidance from their chat.